# How to add button to ckeditor4 standard?

Tags: ckeditor

I need add button chang color font and align paragraph tor right and left and center , there some answers in ckeditor and here but not working with me in  ckeditor.4.4.6

Answer (score 0):

Simply [download the **Full** package](http://ckeditor.com/download) - it should contain all plugins that you listed, [see the comparison here](http://ckeditor.com/presets).